# Can I develop multi tenancy application by using axon framework and spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, saas, axon, axon-framework

I want to implement **multi tenancy application by using `Axon Framework`, `Spring Boot` and `MongoDB`** in my current project. Currently the application is running in a single tenant manner. The approach is to create separate mongo database per tenant. The issue we are facing is how to store and save events in the specific tenant database. Couldn't find any class method to override and add tenant id(database name) to fetch or save events in the database.

We are using `Axon Framework 4.1.1` and `axon-mongodb` extension.

Could you please let me know if this can be done *(and if so how)*? Any high level code would be useful?

Comment: There are [some discussions on AxonIQ's discuss platform](https://discuss.axoniq.io/search?q=tenant%20order%3Alatest) that you may want to have a look at (if you haven't already).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen the provided forum and it talks more about multitenancy in RDMS rather than MongoDB. Currently, As our  approach is to create Mongo database per tenant. Looking forward to get a solution/idea in this direction?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you are using MongoDB as the event store in Axon, I'd like to give a warning. The current implementation, in AxonIQ's frame of mind, does not provide the necessary benefits you need from an Event Store over time. Going into detail why this is the case would be a bit much here, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=342tqAORbAM) video explains it nicely (Mongo is discussed at about 25minutes in the presentation).

When it comes to implementing multi-tenancy in an Axon application, Milen's comment on your message would actually be sufficient. There is nothing really different about the process between MongoDb or an RDBMS, or Axon Server for that matter. You would need to configure your stores nonetheless, which is no concern of the fact you need to support multi-tenancy.

What you do need to construct yourself, is a means to select the right store whenever publication happens. This will, as you rightfully noted, require some custom tooling on the level of your events. So, that would likely require the construction of a specific `EventStore` implementation that fetches a tenant id from the event's metadata and selects the right store to publish the event too. Definitely doable (as I've seen this being done at other party's), but not provided out of the box in Axon.

Note that Axon Server could very well make this process simpler, although I understand that might not be a feasible solution for you at this point in time.